# Is there a way to spy on XHR request with a specific request body in cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm using cy.wait() to spy on PUT requests to a specified URL. I want to spy on unstubbed request.

Comment: What you mean by `unstubbed` request? All request sent form app?

Comment: In a specific it block, I visit root of our app, click on a tab, and click on a filter option. Upon selecting a filter option (like Last hour, last 4 hours etc) app makes a PUT to preferences service. I want to wait on a request with a specific option (like 4 hours) in request body.